# Not writing to file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, web-scraping

I am using selenium to scrape a website and I have stored all the links in a.txt.  Now, I wish to scrape individual links from each of those websites and write to b.txt. problem is, my code does not write to the second and file and I do not know why. I am printing the scrapped values to the console and it works perfectly fine. It just doesn't write to the file b.txt

Any ideas what Could've gone wrong? Below is my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

file1 = 'a.txt'
file2 = 'b.txt'
xpath = '//*[@id="jw"]/div[2]/video'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
videos = []
j = 0
so = open(file2, 'w')
with open(file1, 'r') as fo:
    for url in fo:
        driver.get(url)
        wait = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath))
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(wait)
        video = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
        link = str(video.get_attribute('src'))
        so.write(link + '\n')
        videos.append(link)
        j += 1
        print j
        print link
        print videos
so.close()
```

Comment: add a newline before `so.close()`

Comment: How would a new line help? @user1

Comment: Well I tried the exact same in console what you did and...don't ask me why...but it worked then. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I don't see a single line in my b.txt, while I can see the links being printed in  the terminal. I even tried restarting my pc @user1

Comment: what if you remove all `link` parsing and write data from `file1` directly `so.write(url)`? Or if you replace `for url in fo` with `for x in range(0,3)` and then simply below `so.write(str(x))`? Does blank, raw writing of your file work then?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that your code only writes the first time around (looks like some typo in your question that confuses me a bit), but if thats the case, maybe you need to append

```
open(file1, 'a')
```

instead of

```
open(file1, 'r')
```

Comment: Nah. I've written another code for collecting the urls in a.txt. This is the second part of code, where I am trying to use the links gathered from the first code in a.txt to scrape the webpages to get new data in b.txt